# AdBlock Plus issue with image inside folder/subfolder

Tags: html, image, adblock

Currently I am developing a website. I am trying to link an image via img tag but it doesn't seem to appear on the website.
Here is how I'm linking it:

```
<img src="images/social/facebook.png">
```

The facebook.png image is located inside a images folder which then has a sub folder called 'social'.

I believe I have linked it correctly because when I directly visit http://example.com/images/social/facebook.png the image appears on the browser. **As of writing this post**, I have inspected the website using Chrome developer tools. Developer tools says: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT". I have researched this error up and most sources say that the content is blocked by an extension such as AdBlocker.

That brings me to the question of, why does AdBlock Plus block this image? And why is it that if I put the image on the root of the website, `e.g src="facebook.png"`, AdBlock Plus doesn't block it.

Comment: @Aakash, No, I am on a Windows PC.

Comment: Did you try changing the image file's name and try?

Comment: http://support.getadblock.com/kb/other-problems/adblock-is-blocking-something-that-isnt-an-ad It might be due to folder /social/ try renaming it.